# Users getting "pop-ups blocked" in my website

Tags: android, google-chrome, web, ads, virus

I don't have any "window.open" and have no intentional pop-ups on my website at all.

However, a number of users on different devices and countries seem to be getting "pop-ups blocked" alerts **only** when using my website, since ~1 or ~2 weeks ago.

This seems to be only happening on Android, using Chrome (includes Chrome from the Play Store, Samsung Browser and stock browser, I believe, based on the version numbers), and different devices (mostly Samsung, but there are cases on LG, Huawei and ZTE).

I have an LG and tried every single browser I could (including Samsung Browser), and I don't get any pop-ups. Other users on Samsung also don't get pop-ups. No complaints from iPhone or Desktop users.

I am extremely careful with coding on my website and I'm pretty sure nothing in my code could create a pop-up. In terms of 3rd party, I include jQuery and Fonts from "googleapis.com" and "jquery.com". I also have Google AdSense and Google Analytics.

If you want to have a look, the website is "similarworlds.com" (we don't show ads at logged out view).

**Have you ever seen this happening before, or do you know what this could be, and how can it be resolved?** I'm suspecting a number of users got a Virus, but I can't understand how it suddenly started at the same time and users claim it's only on my website.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

[image: Full Ad]

Comment: nothing strange here; https://imgur.com/lMnNw0Gl.png

Comment: might be the user pirated apps filled with click jackers as is the case many times in android

Comment: @sudorm-rf. Like I said, I use Google Analytics and Google AdSense. Loads of websites do. I don't think Google would suddenly cause intentional pop-ups for a number of users like that.

Comment: its not your fault the, user has malware; see this https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/573081-hellhole/76471725

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the users so far that have complained about this seem to be using a Samsung phone, and after we investigated a bit, this seems to be caused by a virus/infection, and not by my website.

I can see that other people are having this issue recently with other websites.

They seem to be able to resolve this issue by uninstalling apps that have been installed recently.

References:

http://www.fredmiranda.com/forum/topic/1537477

https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/573081-hellhole/76471725

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/insecure-content-and-spam-redirect-from-wordads-unit/

Installing an anti-virus app from the Play Store appears to be resolving the issue for some users.

[image]

[image]